# materriel -ui ToggleButton looks like button

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a ToggleButton
I want the selection to look like a button
But when I put a button inside I get such an error in the console

```
  const StyledToggleButtonGroup = withStyles((theme) => ({
    grouped: {
      margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
      border: 'none',
    },
  }))(ToggleButtonGroup);
```

```
 <StyledToggleButtonGroup size="medium" value={problem} exclusive onChange={handleChange}>
          <ToggleButton color="red" value="technical" className={helpClasses.boxButton}>
            <Button size="medium" fullWidth color="primary" variant="outlined">
              {t('help.technical')}
            </Button>
          </ToggleButton>
        </StyledToggleButtonGroup>
        <DialogActions>
```

error in console

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>.
```

I want it to look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it so

```
const classes = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  boxToggleButton: {
    borderRadius: '5px',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    border: 1,
    width: '6vw',
    height: '6vw',
  },
  textToggleButton: {
    color: colors.light.background,
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: fontSizes.large,
  },
}));
```

```
<ToggleButton value="Wrong identification ">
  <Grid
    container
    justify="center"
    alignItems="center"
    item
    className={classes.boxToggleButton}
  >
    <Typography className={classes.textToggleButton}>
      {"wrongIdentification"}
    </Typography>
  </Grid>
</ToggleButton>;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, https://material-ui.com/components/toggle-button/

It says, you can put icons inside `ToggleButton`, or most likely anything other than `Button`.

Try follow the doc,

```
<ToggleButtonGroup
      value={alignment}
      exclusive
      onChange={handleAlignment}
      aria-label="text alignment"
    >
      <ToggleButton value="left" aria-label="left aligned">
        <FormatAlignLeftIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="center" aria-label="centered">
        <FormatAlignCenterIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="right" aria-label="right aligned">
        <FormatAlignRightIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="justify" aria-label="justified" disabled>
        <FormatAlignJustifyIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
```